# Does the Google wave / Apache Wave protocol support peer-to-peer sync?

Tags: git, synchronization, distributed, p2p, google-wave

... to be more specific, is it possible to "download" all data (including change history) from one "server" to another (or make local copy, like in git) ?

In more broad terms: does it support a git-like model of making changes offline and syncing them between peers?

A quick Google search does not reveal the answer.
And I imagine that to read through the whole Google Wave spec/source code to understand the answer to my question, would be an overkill at this point...

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question fully, but according to the [Project Brief on the Apache wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WAVE/Project+Brief), last modified in April 2016, "NOSQL database layer to sit below the server to store wave related data to allow for data consistency and structure, multiple db's can be supported but two main options should be Cassandra and MongoDB."